# Is the UN a tool of US foreign aims?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, united-nations

While not systematically observing through electronic media US foreign policy actions, I've come to my own conclusion that UN serves mainly to further US foreign aims. Did I draw the wrong conclusion? Are there cases where the UN has taken action that helped non US powers achieve foreign policy objectives that the US opposes?

Comment: You should probably 1) Narrow this question to be more specific and 2) Explain how you came to this conclusion.

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE; as I observed, you didn't take the tour. Please consider take the tour: http://politics.stackexchange.com/tour and then rewrite your answer with your conclusions, that seems legit but I can't understand how you came in that conclusion or what are your sources.

Comment: The US is influential within the UN, but no more so than when dealing with individual countries. In fact, less so as countries such as Russia and China can veto anything they put forward should they choose to.

Comment: Define irony: a large chunk of US (myself included) are firmly convinced that UN is mostly a tool of those with anti-US agenda.

Answer (score 6):

If the UN existed to serve US foreign aims, then why do they have to waste so much time doing things like vetoing sanctions against Israel, and why then refuse to sign onto International bodies and instruments like the World Court or Kyoto?

Has the US tried to further their own interests through the UN? Sure. That's what it is there for. It is a forum to discuss areas of mutual interest by your country, so every county approaches politics from the perspectives of it's own interests. Some countries are more of the mind that their interest is best served by the common good than others, but that is still an expression of what they believe to be their interests.

But it is not a US-centric body by any means, and certainly is not in its service.

Comment: Actually by "countries" you mean their regimes, not their populations. The UN serves the interest of many dictatorial regimes against their own populations across the world.

Comment: AFAK  all sanctions against Israel are "paper tiger" ?

Comment: @DusanSukovic - not really, for a variety of reasons.